# FacebookSDK - Loginscreen has wrong layout size

Tags: ios, layout, cocos2d-x, facebook-login, facebook-sdk-3.1

I am using cocos2d-x (c++) & soomlaProfile for my game.

I want to login into Facebook via FacebookSDK. If I click on the fb-login-button the popup-window from facebook appears, but the layout is wrong.

[image: all areas are displaced]

Comment: It seems to be some bug of FacebookSDK. There is nothing that need to be set for showing a facebook login dialog.

Comment: It seems to be some bugs of FacebookSDK. There is nothing that need to be set for showing a facebook login dialog.